# Find xml tag and replace the text inside the tag to a parameter value multiple occurrences

Tags: sed, xml, parameter

Find a specific xml tag and replace the text inside tags to some parameterized value. Multiple occurrences need to be replaced.

Sample file content:

```
<a>abc</a>
```

Current attempt:

```
sed -i "s/\(<a>\).*\(<\/a>\)/\(<a>\)$param\(<\/a>\)/g" script.xml
```

Desired outcome: if param=111 then

```
<a>111</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your post is rather hard to understand as it is. Please use proper [formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to highlight (1) sample input (2) what you already tried (3) where you ran into problems - it is currently not clear what your question/problem actually is.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a `sed` solution, but I generally recommend an XML-based tool (of which there are a number) instead of `sed` when dealing with an XML document other than a very simple one.

Suppose this is my XML document (`doc.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
    <c><a>abc</a></c>
    <b>
        <a>abc</a>
        <a>abc</a>
    </b>
    <a parm="FPM">abc</a>
</xml>
```

I am going to use the following XML stylesheet, `style.xsl`, to transform the document into the desired format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name = "value" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a/text()[.='abc']">
        <xsl:value-of select = "$value" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use the `xsltproc` tool, which is installed by default on most major Linux distributions, to perform the transformation:

```
$ xsltproc --stringparam value "111" style.xsl doc.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
    <c><a>111</a></c>
    <b>
        <a>111</a>
        <a>111</a>
    </b>
    <a parm="FPM">111</a>
</xml>
$
```

Answer (score 2):

My preferred tool to edit XML files is `xmlstarlet`. Suppose this is my XML document ([`doc.xml`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593856/100397)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
    <c><a>abc</a></c>
    <b>
        <a>abc</a>
        <a>abc</a>
    </b>
    <a parm="FPM">abc</a>
</xml>
```

Here's the `xmlstarlet` command:

```
param=111
xmlstarlet edit --ps --update '//a' --value "$param" doc.xml
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
    <c><a>111</a></c>
    <b>
        <a>111</a>
        <a>111</a>
    </b>
    <a parm="FPM">111</a>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Those `\(\)` are superfluous in your case. Just write `sed -i "s/<a>.*<\/a>/<a>$param<\/a>/g" script.xml`
2. If your string contains `/`, it's easier to read if you use a different separator char: `sed -i "s_<a>.*</a>_<a>$param</a>_g" script.xml`
3. The `g` option suggests that there could be more than one `<a>` tag on one line. This is a problem: The `.*` will match the next `</a>`, more stuff and the last `<a>`, so prevent to include other tags: `sed -i "s_<a>[^<]*</a>_<a>$param</a>_g" script.xml`
4. Please note that this will not work if other tags are nested inside the `<a>` tag or if `$param` contains special characters like `"` or `\`

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in Perl instead of `sed` since Perl supports non-greedy matches:

```
perl -i -pe "s|<a>.+?</a>|<a>$param</a>|g" file
```

The `.+?` means "match the shortest possible string", so this will find the shortest string between an `<a>` and an `</a>`.

I must stress, however, that this is very likely to fail on even slightly complex XML documents and you really should consider using a dedicated XML parser instead.