# How to replace, in an XML file, specific strings of characters in some specified tags with other strings of characters embedded in tags

Tags: text-processing, xml

I need to replace, in an XML file, specific strings of characters in some specified tags with other strings of characters embedded in tags.

Example searching every occurance of `an example`, that needs to be replaced by `<b>a test</b>` only if it is within the `<a> ... </a>` tag (inside other tags):

- Input example:

  ```xml
  <c>This is an example. <a>This is an example;</a></c>
  ```
- Desired output:

  ```xml
  <c>This is an example. <a>This is <b>a test;</b></a></c>
  ```

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to linux / unix and a general XSLT problem – > might be much, much better off at Stackoverflow.ocm than here!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I would assume instead that it's about how to make the appropriate tools perform the necessary change. Here, for example, the `<a>This is *an example*</a>` needs to be changed to `<a>This is </a>` with an embedded element `<d>a test</d>`. The XSLT came from [fpmurphy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593856/100397) to the cross-referenced question.

Comment: Indeed, I would like to generalise the answer given in this forum, so I believe it is the correct place to ask it. More specifically, I do not know what kind of wildcard I need to use to search for just a group of specified characters, and not the whole chain of characters within a tag. In addition, I do not know how to deal with the XML tags in the replacing group of characters. I tried using xmlstarlet as presented here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608341/using-sed-to-replace-substrings-between-specific-tags, but ran into the issue, a.o., of the special characters "<" and ">".

Comment: I only wish to add formatting tags in an XML file that is a DB export (and that is partly tagged), but these additional tags should only be placed to specific chains of characters that are embedded in specific tags. The XML file is then imported in InDesign. So it is not about XML transformation.

Comment: Please move it to StackOverflow and tag it XSLT. You're much more likely to get it answered there.

Comment: I removed the XSL part, as I believe this is misleading. I just need to do a complex/conditional search and replace within tags, either using SED, GREP, xmlstarlet or any other unix command line. From what I have read, the use of XSL was one possible way to do that.

Comment: [Conventional wisdom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3960947)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to

1. remove the text `an example;` from the value of the `/c/a` node in the XML document, and
2. add a sub-node to the `/c/a` node called `b`, with the value `a test;`.

You can easily do this with `xmlstarlet` in the shell:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed -u '/c/a' -x 'substring-before(text(), "an example;")' file.xml |
xmlstarlet ed -s '/c/a' -t elem -n 'b' -v 'a test;'
```

The first invocation of `xmlstarlet` on the example document in the question would result in the following output, where some text is removed from the `/c/a` node's value:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<c>This is an example. <a>This is </a></c>
```

The second invocation takes this modified document and produces the following by introducing the `/c/a/b` node:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<c>This is an example. <a>This is <b>a test;</b></a></c>
```

The `xmlstarlet` invocations may be combined into a single command.  Below, I've used the long options and also use `--inplace` for in-place editing of the original document (this is for illustration only, you should run without `--inplace` to determine the transformations works first):

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed --inplace \
    --update  '/c/a' -x 'substring-before(text(), "an example;")' \
    --subnode '/c/a' -t elem -n 'b' -v 'a test;' file.xml
```

---

A generalisation of the above to something that performs the two edits to any `a` node containing the text `an example;` (which is what was actually requested in the question):

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed \
    --var paths '//a[contains(text(), "an example;")]'  \
    --update  '$paths' -x 'substring-before(text(), "an example;")' \
    --subnode '$paths' -t elem -n 'b' -v 'a test;' file.xml
```

The only new thing here is that we first store the paths for all the nodes we want to edit in the internal variable `$paths`.  We then refer to these paths in the `--update` and `--subnode` modifications.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am now trying on my file, with the exact search and replace I need:       xmlstarlet ed --var paths ‘//CS_CT[contains(text(), “།  །”)]’  --update  '$paths' -x 'substring-before(text(), “།  །“)’   --subnode '$paths' -t elem -n ‘CS_NBSS’ -v ‘།  །’  file_mod.xml             But I have that shell error message: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('       I've checked carefully and believe I followed your syntax. Do you see anything wrong? I've tried with CSCT and CSNBSS, and replacing the Tibetan characters with letters, but still the error is the same

Comment: @Matt5 Your code in the comment does not use straight quotes (`"` and `'`), but typographical ("fancy") quotes as written by some word processors (`“` and `‘`).  This is going to cause issues in the shell.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry... I would like to know what would be your answer for an example searching every occurance of `an example`, that needs to be replaced by `<b>a test</b>` only if it is **NOT** within the `<a> ... </a>` tag (inside other tags):
* Input example:
    ```xml
    <c>This is an example. <a>This is an example;</a></c>
    ```
* Desired output:
    ```xml
    <c>This is <b>a test.</b> <a>This is an example;</a></c>
    ```

Comment: I have asked a related question in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/701641/523366.