# How to rename, in an XML file, specific tags that are embedded in some other specific tags

Tags: text-processing, xml, xmlstarlet

What is the xmlstarlet command to replace a tag value by another one, only for specified tags embedded in other specified tags?

Example: searching every occurance of the tag `b`, that needs to be replaced by `d` only if it is within the `<a> ... </a>` tag (inside other tags):

- Input example:

  ```xml
  <c>This is <b>an example</b>. <a>This is <b>a test;</b></a></c>
  ```
- Desired output:

  ```xml
  <c>This is <b>an example</b>. <a>This is <d>a test;</d></a></c>
  ```

This post is related to [How to replace, in an XML file, specific strings of characters in some specified tags with other strings of characters embedded in tags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/700179/523366) in the solution I am trying to find to format xml files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```bsh
$ cat file 
<c>This is <b>an example</b>. <a>This is <b>a test;</b></a></c>
```

```bsh
$ xmlstarlet ed --rename '//a/b' -v 'd' file 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<c>This is <b>an example</b>. <a>This is <d>a test;</d></a></c>
```

This renames all `b` nodes that occur directly under an `a` node.  The new name for these nodes will be `d`.  Since I'm using `//` in front of `a/b` in the XPath expression, it does not matter where the `a` node is located within the document structure.