# How to untag, in an XML file, a chain of tagged characters that are embedded within specified tags

Tags: text-processing, xml, xmlstarlet

What is the xmlstarlet command to untag, in an XML file, a chain of tagged characters that are embedded within specified tags?

Example: searching every occurrence of the tag `<b>`, that needs to be deleted only if it is within the `<c> ... </c>` tag:

- Input example:

  ```xml
  <c>This is <b>an example</b>. <a>This is <b>a test;</b></a></c>
  ```
- Desired output:

  ```xml
  <c>This is an example. <a>This is <b>a test;</b></a></c>
  ```

For the sake of generalization, I am keeping the second sentence in the example, i.e.

```xml
<a>This is <b>a test;</b></a>
```

but if it is an issue, it can be ignored.

Comment: wait, but your second sentence is *also* within the same `<c>`! So, you only want to delete if the `b` is **directly** a child element of `c`, and not transitively?

Comment: II moved our discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136118/discussion-on-question-by-matt5-how-to-untag-in-an-xml-file-a-chain-of-tagged), @marcus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with an `--update` to copy the value of the `//c/b` nodes into their parent nodes, then `--delete` to delete the now unwanted `b` nodes.

This is similar to the approach I took at the end of [one of my previous answers to your questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701153/116858), where I first create an internal `xmlstarlet` variable that holds the set of all the nodes that we need to process and then process these.  We do this to more easily access the same set of nodes for both the update and the deletion operation.  In the previous answer, this was *neccesary*, but here it's merely for readability.

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed \
    --var 'path' '//c/b' \
    --update '$path/../text()[1]' --expr 'concat(., $path/text())' \
    --delete '$path' file.xml
```

Worth noting here is that the update doesn't target the `b` node's parent, but the parent's *first text value*, `text()[1]`.  The first text value in of the `//c/b` node's parent in the example document is the string `This is` .  The *second* text value is `.`  after the `b` node.  Had we selected without `[1]` at the end, we would have ended up with

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<c>This is an example. an example<a>This is <b>a test;</b></a></c>
```

That is, the string `an example` would have been inserted after both text values of the `c` node.

Now, instead, we get

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<c>This is an example. <a>This is <b>a test;</b></a></c>
```

Comment: @Matt5 This sounds like a new question to me. I can't quite picture how this would look, so a new question with some examples would be good. An XML parser should not care about whitespace, so it would be good if you could describe _in what way_ InDesign cares about this too.